# Calling async_result.get() from within a celery task

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery task that calls another **remote** task (it's on a different celery app, in another server..).
When I try to .get() the result of that remote task from within my task like this:

```
@app.task()
def my_local_task():
  result_from_remote = app.send_task('remote_task', [arg1, arg2])
  return result_from_remote.get()
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task! See http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks

In Celery 3.2 this will result in an exception being
raised instead of just being a warning.

  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(E_WOULDBLOCK))
```

Basically I want my task to be "synchronous" - I want it to wait for the result of the remote task, and i'm ok with it.

Can I tell celery it's ok?
There is the solution of chaining of course, except it's impossible to chain remote tasks. The only way to call remote tasks is using app.send_task, which returns an AsyncResult, and that I can't chain as I need the task function itself..

Comment: I opened a bug about it: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3498

Comment: Celery <3.2 lets you do it, just gives a warning. I downgraded my Celery version just because of this, but I'll try using some workaround now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your task to be synchronous, you can use `ready()` to hold a loop:

```
import time

while not result_from_remote.ready():
    time.sleep(5)

return result_from_remote.get()
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did eventually. I wonder why they don't enable people suppressing this warning (and error later)

Comment: Confirming that this works around the warning that appears in the celery log. I think the warning issued by celery is incorrect. There are valid use cases where one would want to wait for task completion and where dead lock is impossible.

Answer (score 27):

Here is a fragment that hushes the warning if you know what you are doing is safe:

```
from celery.result import allow_join_result

with allow_join_result():
    result.get()
```

[source](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3498#issuecomment-252705043)

Comment: I'm use celery 3. Perhaps log a bug with the developers. The "source" link I provided is to the github project. One of the developers provided the information.

Answer (score 1):

> There is the solution of chaining of course, except it's impossible to chain remote tasks. The only way to call remote tasks is using app.send_task, which returns an AsyncResult, and that I can't chain as I need the task function itself..

No, **it is possible to chain remote tasks.** I've just tried it in a project of mine and it works. I suggest you try it with a trivial test task first to make sure you got the basics down before moving to something more complex. I've created these tasks:

```
@app.task
def foo(arg):
    return arg + 1

@app.task
def bar(arg):
    return "I barred " + str(arg)
```

The two tasks are held in a module named `app.tasks`. (It is part of a Django project.)

Then I wrote a command that does:

```
import celery
print (celery.signature("app.tasks.foo", args=(1, )) |
       celery.signature("app.tasks.bar")).delay().get()
```

And I got on the screen:

```
I barred 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with celery 4

```
@app.task()
def my_local_task():
    result_from_remote = app.send_task('remote_task', [arg1, arg2])

    while not result_from_remote.ready():
        time.sleep(1)

    return result_from_remote.result
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps. You can use the edit link below your answer to improve the post.