# What is the proper way to call a Celery task from within a task when I need to get the result and there is only one worker?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery

I have a celery queue with a single worker (`--concurrency=1`). I have two tasks. One which calls an API (`call_api_task`). The other (`other_task`) calls a function which in turn calls the API task and waits for the result.

```
def update_data():
    data_to_api = '{"hello": "world"}'
    api_response = call_api_task.subtask(data_to_api).delay().get()
    return api_response

@celery.task
def call_api_task(data_to_api):
    # Call api with data_to_api
    return '{"success": "true"}'

@celery.task
def other_task():
    response = update_data()
    # Do something with response
```

The problem I'm running in to is that when `other_task` is called, it never completes. Based on the [Celery docs](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#designing-workflows) I thought that calling the task as a subtask should avoid this problem, but it seems I am missing something.

### Possible resolutions I have considered

1. Add a parameter to `update_data` which allows it to know that it was called from `other_task`. Then call `call_api_task` without `subtask` & `delay`.

   - Problem: In the nontrivial example code there are several other functions between `other_task` and `update_data` which means I would have to pass that parameter around a lot. This would result in messy code.
2. Add code in `update_data` to detect if it was called via a Celery task by checking `billiard.current_process()` properties.

   - Problem: It seems like there should be a  more elegant way to accomplish this.
3. Put `other_task` on a different Celery queue.

   - This is what I am currently doing to solve the problem. I thought there should be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

### Question

How can `update_data` call `call_api_task` directly (not as a task) when called from `other_task` without using possible resolution #1 or #2 above?

### In response to possible duplicate of [Calling async_result.get() from within a celery task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280456)

This question & answers are specifically addressing "a celery task that calls another remote task (it's on a different celery app, in another server..)". This is not the case for my scenario. As pointed out above, I could put `other_task` on a separate Celery queue which would give the same end result as the scenario of this question but I thought there should be a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling async\_result.get() from within a celery task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280456/calling-async-result-get-from-within-a-celery-task)

Comment: @Louis I disagree. I did look at that question/answer and in this case I don't think it will help. My task is running on the same queue with a single worker. That question is in regards to "a celery task that calls another remote task (it's on a different celery app, in another server..)".

Comment: It does not matter that it is "running on the same queue with a single worker". This is just an instance that falls under the general rule "don't wait for task results within a celery task", which the other question addresses. Your case is just one where deadlock is guaranteed because your number of workers is 1 whereas in the general case deadlock is only *possible* (depending on whether or not all workers are busy).

Comment: @Louis I've updated the question to make it more clear that this is not a duplicate of the question you noted.

Comment: @Louis I agree, I don't want to wait for a task result within a task. I've reworded my question again, hopefully it is more clear now. I'm not understanding how any of the answers in that other question will help solve my scenario. I am specifically trying to find a way to not call `call_api_task` as a task when `update_data` is called from `other_task`. It really seems like there should be an elegant solution for this so that `update_data` can detect it's already running inside a Celery task and just call `call_api_task` directly (as a non-task function).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for a Celery API that will cleanly do this.

FWIW, you could subclass `Task` in a so that you'll get the property you're looking for without changing the code very much from your example. I removed `subtask`.

Notes - This uses the `billiard` method but isolates it to just one part of your codebase. If `billiard` isn't an option, you could use `inspect`... but that's uglier IMO. You might be able to use `billiard.current_process().daemon` instead of the more crude string matching illustrated below.

Otherwise, there are also some interesting environment variable approaches here: [How can I detect whether I'm running in a Celery worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003282/how-can-i-detect-whether-im-running-in-a-celery-worker)

```
# Python 3
def update_data():
    """ OP's method without subtask """
    data_to_api = '{"hello": "world"}'
    api_response = call_api_task.delay(data_to_api).get()
    return api_response


class DummyAsyncResult():
    """
    Provides a get() method that returns the value it's initialized with.
    """
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def get(self):
        return self.value


class DelayOnceTask(Task):
    """
    Running .delay() returns a DummyAsyncResult instance if called
    from within a celery worker. Otherwise behaves like a `Task`
    """
    def delay(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'PoolWorker' in billiard.current_process()._name:
            return DummyAsyncResult(self(*args, **kwargs))
        else:
            return super().delay(*args, **kwargs)
```