# How can I detect whether I'm running in a Celery worker?

Tags: python, celery

Is there a way to determine, programatically, that the current module being imported/run is done so in the context of a celery worker?

We've settled on setting an environment variable before running the Celery worker, and checking this environment variable in the code, but I wonder if there's a better way?

Comment: `celery.current_app` maybe?

Answer (score 22):

Simple,

```
import sys

IN_CELERY_WORKER_PROCESS = sys.argv and sys.argv[0].endswith('celery')\
    and 'worker' in sys.argv

if IN_CELERY_WORKER_PROCESS:
    print ('Im in Celery worker')
```

http://percentl.com/blog/django-how-can-i-detect-whether-im-running-celery-worker/

Comment: Now I'm using the same solution, something like `if 'worker' in sys.argv`, but I'm worried about what if another person imported my project and he also use the parameters 'worker' in his celery project.

Comment: Link appears to be dead

Comment: On my machine, when in the worker `sys.argv[0]` ends in `'celery/__main__.py'`, not `'celery'`.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what your use-case scenario is exactly, you may be able to detect it by checking whether the request id is set:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def foo(self):
    print self.request.id
```

If you invoke the above as `foo.delay()` then the task will be sent to a worker and `self.request.id` will be set to a unique number. If you invoke it as `foo()`, then it will be executed in your current process and `self.request.id` will be `None`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `current_worker_task` property from the `Celery` application instance class. [Docs here.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.current_worker_task)

With the following task defined:

```
 # whatever_app/tasks.py

 celery_app = Celery(app)

 @celery_app.task
 def test_task():
     if celery_app.current_worker_task:
         return 'running in a celery worker'
     return 'just running'
```

You can run the following on a python shell:

```
In [1]: from whatever_app.tasks import test_task

In [2]: test_task()
Out[2]: 'just running'

In [3]: r = test_task.delay()

In [4]: r.result
Out[4]: u'running in a celery worker'
```

**Note:** Obviously for `test_task.delay()` to succeed, you need to have at least one celery worker running and configured to load tasks from `whatever_app.tasks`.

Comment: Couldn't this produce a false positive if Celery is executing another task on a worker, while this is being executed offline?

Answer (score 3):

As of celery 4.2 you can also do this by setting a flag on the `worker_ready` signal

in `celery.py`:

```
from celery.signals import worker_ready
app = Celery(...)
app.running = False

@worker_ready.connect
def set_running(*args, **kwargs):
    app.running = True
```

Now you can check within your task by using the global app instance
to see whether or not you are running.  This can be very useful to determine which logger to use.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a environment variable is a good way to check if the module is being run by celery worker. In the task submitter process we may set the environment variable, to mark that it is not running in the context of a celery worker.

But the better way may be to use some celery signals which may help to know if the module is running in worker or task submitter. For example, [worker-process-init](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-init) signal is sent to each child task executor process (in preforked mode) and the handler can be used to set some global variable indicating it is a worker process.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to know if I'm a worked much earlier (when I import my tasks...). So the envvar is the only way I could move forward...

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to start workers with names, so that it becomes easier to manage(stop/kill/restart) them. You can use `-n` to name a worker.

```
celery worker -l info -A test -n foo
```

Now, in your script you can use `app.control.inspect` to see if that worker is running.

```
In [22]: import test

In [23]: i = test.app.control.inspect(['foo'])

In [24]: i.app.control.ping()
Out[24]: [{'celery@foo': {'ok': 'pong'}}]
```

You can read more [about this in celery worker docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#inspecting-workers)