# How to exclude a function outside a Celery worker?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, celery, background-process

I have a web app built on Flask. I use Celery to get background tasks. But I have a function that loads an object detection model onto the memory and it consumes a large part. I have 5 workers and 2 of them are Celery workers.

I don't want Celery to load this object detection model because it's unnecessary. How can I exclude this function from a Celery worker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to programmatically find out if you're inside a Celery worker, you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50843002/1016216).

Comment: I've solved it using the approved question, thank you very much.